# Two stage model - first stage logit and second stage OLS

Tags: logistic, least-squares

I would like to run a two stage model where I estimate a logit regression to estimate the likelihood of an event happening followed by a *conditional* OLS - where the condition is - provided the event happens I estimate an OLS. Is there such a model?

For context - I have bond-level trade data that is extremely sparse - very few trades happen as the market is highly illiquid. So, the objective of my first stage is to figure out the likelihood of a trade happening - on firm-level factors and market participant factors. Once I have the likelihood, the objective of the second stage is - provided the bond trade happens - what firm-level factors affect the value of the bond trade.

My current implementation is as follows - run the logit on the entire data set to get the odds-ratio. I then filter out only those datapoints where a bond trade *does* happen and then run OLS on this smaller dataset. Is this correct? Or is there a way I can combine these two specifications?

Comment: yeah, I believe a procedure like this is called a 'hurdle' model and has a plethora of research on the topic.

Comment: Thanks! This is precisely what I needed.